# Ways to delete indexeddb on beforeunload

Tags: storage, indexeddb, onbeforeunload

I am saving data from the user in an indexeddb. When the user closes my app (i.e. the browser), I want to delete this storage. However, since IndexedDB requests are asynchronous, they won't be executed on `beforeunload`. This is why I am curious to see, how other people solved this issue? Is there any way at all?

Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer that taken from MDN:

> The synchronous API being intended for use only with Web Workers. The synchronous version was removed from the spec because its need was questionable, however it may be reintroduced in the future if there is enough demand from web developers.

Comment: So I guess it's wait and see. But from my perspective it makes sense, since some webapps might want to make sure, that the data is gone, once the site is closed, e.g. due to security / copyright concern when using streaming together with peer to peer technology to reduce server requests or their size.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the user can *always* see your IDB/LocalStorage data via dev tools.